# How to check UUID validity in Python?

Tags: python, uuid

I have a string that should be a UUID. Is there any built-in Python function available to check whether the UUID is valid or not, and to check its version?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I found this question while I was looking for a Python answer. To help people in the same situation, I've added the **Python** solution.

You can use the [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) module:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from uuid import UUID

def is_valid_uuid(uuid_to_test, version=4):
    """
    Check if uuid_to_test is a valid UUID.
    
     Parameters
    ----------
    uuid_to_test : str
    version : {1, 2, 3, 4}
    
     Returns
    -------
    `True` if uuid_to_test is a valid UUID, otherwise `False`.
    
     Examples
    --------
    >>> is_valid_uuid('c9bf9e57-1685-4c89-bafb-ff5af830be8a')
    True
    >>> is_valid_uuid('c9bf9e58')
    False
    """
    
    try:
        uuid_obj = UUID(uuid_to_test, version=version)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return str(uuid_obj) == uuid_to_test


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Python won't always raise a ValueError. It will sometimes silently fix the input.
uuid.UUID('6a3f6f5c-8df8-5b4e-8ec3-a8b2df62a40b', version=4)                                                                                           
UUID('6a3f6f5c-8df8-4b4e-8ec3-a8b2df62a40b')
mind the (5b4e-block in the middle!)

Comment: Be aware that `str(uuid_obj) == uuid_to_test` will cause valid uuids (but without dashes) to be identified as invalid. Because `UUID(uuid_to_test)` will add them even if not provided at first.

Comment: Why do you think leaving the dashes away is valid? Is there a standard which defines them as optional? Can arbitrary many dashes be added?

Comment: @MartinThoma I'm not sure about the standards honestly but `uuid.UUID` itself considers it [valid](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/730902c0ad997462d2567e48def5352fe75c0e2c/Lib/uuid.py#L153) and it actually removes any dashes before constructing the uuid object as you can see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/730902c0ad997462d2567e48def5352fe75c0e2c/Lib/uuid.py#L176)

Answer (score 51):

All the existing answers use regex. If you're using **Python**, you might want to consider a `try/except` in case you don't want to use regex:
*(Bit shorter than the answer above).*

Our validator would then be:

```py
import uuid

def is_valid_uuid(val):
    try:
        uuid.UUID(str(val))
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

```
>>> is_valid_uuid(1)
False
>>> is_valid_uuid("123-UUID-wannabe")
False
>>> is_valid_uuid({"A":"b"})
False
>>> is_valid_uuid([1, 2, 3])
False
>>> is_valid_uuid(uuid.uuid4())
True
>>> is_valid_uuid(str(uuid.uuid4()))
True
>>> is_valid_uuid(uuid.uuid4().hex)
True
>>> is_valid_uuid(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, 'example.net'))
True
>>> is_valid_uuid(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, 'example.net'))
True
>>> is_valid_uuid("{20f5484b-88ae-49b0-8af0-3a389b4917dd}")
True
>>> is_valid_uuid("20f5484b88ae49b08af03a389b4917dd")
True
```

Comment: Watch out for UUID syntax variants that uuid.UUID() accepts: "{20f5484b-88ae-49b0-8af0-3a389b4917dd}", "20f5484b88ae49b08af03a389b4917dd"

Comment: Thanks @PēterisCaune nice addition - the case with `.hex` essentially covers the last one you added but it's worth adding regardless. Wasn't aware of the "{uuid}" case.

Comment: Also this is true. `is_valid_uuid('-2b1eb780-8a03-4031-b1e5-2f7674c60df3')` >> True

Answer (score 30):

To check the validity of a UUID string, simply try to create a new `uuid` object with it. If it's invalid...

```
uuid.UUID("foo")
# => ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
```

If you need to know the version of the UUID, it's right there in the [`UUID` API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.version):

```
uuid.UUID('302a4299-736e-4ef3-84fc-a9f400e84b24').version
# => 4
```

Comment: i have to check whether the UUID i have is in proper format or not and its version.

Comment: Try except this using ValueError: `val = UUID(your_uuid_string, version=4)`

Answer (score 8):

```
import re

UUID_PATTERN = re.compile(r'^[\da-f]{8}-([\da-f]{4}-){3}[\da-f]{12}$', re.IGNORECASE)
uuid = '20f5484b-88ae-49b0-8af0-3a389b4917dd'

return bool(UUID_PATTERN.match(uuid))
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit? By the way : `return UUID_PATTERN.match(uuid)`?

Comment: Actually yeah, just return the match is better. What bit do you not understand here?

Comment: By the way - I tested that code and found that re.IGNORECASE is too expensive - much cheaper is apply lower() to uuid